# Integration by Substitution problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given an integration problems sheet...with answers too but how a certain answer is to be obtained is obviuosly not stated.
Using integration by substitution integrate the following:
$$ \int \dfrac{5x +3}{\sqrt{3-x^2}} \, dx$$

And the answer at the back is:
$$ -5 \sqrt{3-x^2} +\arcsin \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right) +C$$

Any idea how i go about the substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that

$$ \int \frac{5x +3 }{\sqrt{3-x^2}}dx= \int \frac{5x  }{\sqrt{3-x^2}}dx
 +\int \frac{ 3 }{\sqrt{3-x^2}}dx$$

For the first integral you can use the substitution $u=3-x^2$ and for the second, express the denominator as $ \sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{\sqrt {3}})^2}
$

Comment: used $u^2 = 3-x^2$ and that worked fine. Thanx alot,when u do things u think are complicated u tend to forget that there are some other simpler ways to view things from ie breaking it into fractions

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use the substitution $x=\sqrt{3}\cdot \sin(u)$.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Here's another hint: this reduces to $5\cdot \sqrt{3}\cdot sin(u) + 3\; du$

Comment: why such a substitution is there a logical explanation behind this?

Comment: Well... you have to evaluate $x'(u)$, since we have to convert the differential form from $dx$ to $du$ in the numerator. So, it is kind of nice when we get the derivative in the denominator.